# How to attach all sheets but first in email using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have got a workbook with 4 sheets:

1st - recipients email data such as `TO`, `CC`, `Subject`, from 2nd to 4th
 the sheets which I need to send as an attachment to the recipients.

I made up the following script. But I faced 2 issues as a VBA beginner:

1. The 'loop' proposes for sending the 1st empty row from the 1st sheet
   as well (I would like to stop with the last email details);
2. The 'ActiveWorkbook' sends all sheets (I would like to skip the 1st
   one where the recipients & the VBA script are located);

I appreciate every advice/remark because I have been studying VBA for 3 months.
 Thank you in advance!

```
Sub ICO_Emails()
    Dim VSEApp As Object
    Dim VSEMail As Object
    Dim VSEText As String
    Dim Email_Send_To, Email_Cc, Email_Subject As String

    row_number = 1

    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        Email_Send_To = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
        Email_Cc = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)
        Email_Subject = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
        On Error GoTo debugs
        Set VSEApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set VSEMail = VSEApp.CreateItem(0)
        'Email Body script
        VSEText = "<BODY style=font-size:14pt;font-family:Times New Roman>Dear all,<p>Test.<p></BODY>"
        'Email Signature
        With VSEMail
            .Display
        End With
        Signature = VSEMail.HTMLBody
        With VSEMail
            .To = Email_Send_To
            .CC = Email_Cc
            .Subject = Email_Subject
            .HTMLBody = VSEText & Signature
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Display
        End With
debugs:
    Loop Until Email_Send_To = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please format your code, it is not readable this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this. This takes a copy of your workbook and saves it to the users "temp" location. It then does the modifications that you want to the copy of the workbook before attaching that.

```
Sub ICO_Emails()
    Dim VSEApp As Object
    Dim VSEMail As Object
    Dim VSEText As String
    Dim Email_Send_To, Email_Cc, Email_Subject As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, nwb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.SaveCopyAs (Environ("temp") & "\temp_" & wb.Name)

    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open(Environ("temp") & "\temp_" & wb.Name)
    With nwb
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ' Delete relevant sheet
        .Sheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Save
    End With

    row_number = 1

    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        Email_Send_To = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
        Email_Cc = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)
        Email_Subject = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
        On Error GoTo debugs
        Set VSEApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set VSEMail = VSEApp.CreateItem(0)
        'Email Body script
        VSEText = "<BODY style=font-size:14pt;font-family:Times New Roman>Dear all,<p>Test.<p></BODY>"
        'Email Signature
        With VSEMail
            .Display
        End With
        Signature = VSEMail.HTMLBody
        With VSEMail
            .To = Email_Send_To
            .CC = Email_Cc
            .Subject = Email_Subject
            .HTMLBody = VSEText & Signature
            .Attachments.Add nwb.FullName
            .Display
        End With
debugs:
    Loop Until Email_Send_To = ""
    nwb.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: DisplayAlerts is set to False twice in a row. You might consider reusing the same Outlook.Application for every iteration too. Upvoted

Comment: Hello Tom, your modifications don't solve my problems. The attched files in each email cannot be open. And the 'loop' again considers the first empty row and proposes it into new blank email.

Answer (score -1):

1. Save a copy of your workbook
2. Open it
3. Remove the sheet from the copy
4. Save
5. Send this edited workbook

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use comments

Comment: It is an answer to the problem he raised, namely that his code sends all of the workbook instead of skipping a sheet. You can answer a question without supplying code that is ready to copy paste. I'd use a comment when I'm not directly answering a question, for example a suggestion not to use.Select or to format the code properly.